# Wordpress: How to remove duplicate CSS, JS and font files?

Tags: wordpress, caching, optimization, render-blocking

On my Wordpress website, I'm getting multiple duplicates of CSS, JS and even Google Fonts (I don't use Google fonts on the website any more).
GTmetrix link:

https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.anantamassage.com/zmmG6cvO

How do I eliminate these duplicate files?

PS. I use 'WP Rocket - Premium' for optimization and caching.

Thank you

[image]
[image]

Comment: I guess it's your cache plugin... Did you tried clearing the cache and check it's settings?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I cleared the website as well as the CDN cache several times. What do you think I have to check in the settings? (any particular thing)?

Comment: I can't be so sure :) How about you mention the used Plugin Cache too? Just add it to your question so it would be more clear...